# How do I set dynamic values for an SPFieldChoice?

Tags: content-type, choice-field

I want to add choices programmatically to an SPFieldChoice so that its select box has values with Current Year - 5 to Current Year + 5.

What is the best way to do this?

Ex:

```
2005
2006
2007
...
2010 -- current year
...
2013
2014
2015
```

Answer (score 2):

Where "spfc" is an object of type SPFieldChoice:

```
int year = DateTime.Now.Year - 5;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    spfc.Choices.Add((year + i).ToString());
}
spfc.Update();
```